# "Defaults closefrom_override" does not work in sudo

Tags: sudo

To allow myself to keep file descriptors open when I invoke `sudo`, I created `/etc/sudoers.d/10-closefrom_override.conf` with the following content:

```
Defaults closefrom_override
```

I try to the `-C` option with `sudo` afterwards and I get:

```
sudo: you are not permitted to use the -C option
```

What is wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Does `sudo -l` list closefrom_override in the output *Matching Defaults*?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing above content in `/etc/sudoers` file rather in `closefrom_override.conf`. This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04